# ruby on rails - cannot load such file -- serialport

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serial-port

I am trying to use serial port by ruby on rails. I use  require 'serialport'. I installed gem serialport.
I have got this error:

```
cannot load such file -- serialport
```

and this line is highlighted:

```
require 'serialport'
```

This is my script:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def hello
    render text: "hello1, world!"
  end

  def cmd
    require 'serialport'

    @result = params[:parametr]
    @dioda = params[:dioda]

    #params for serial port  
    port_str = "/dev/ttyACM0"  #may be different for you  
    baud_rate = 9600  
    data_bits = 8  
    stop_bits = 1  
    parity = SerialPort::NONE  
    sp = SerialPort.new(port_str, baud_rate, data_bits, stop_bits, parity) 

    case @result
      when "1"
        render html: "<strong>Led_on</strong>".html_safe
      when "0"      
        render html: "<strong>Led_off</strong>".html_safe
      when "sos"
        render html: "<strong>Led_sos</strong>".html_safe
    end

    sleep 4
    puts sp.readlines
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Rails, you need to put `gem 'serialport'` in your `Gemfile` and then run `bundle install`.

Comment: Yes , I use Rails. I installed gem 'serial'. This is output from my console:
greg@dom-NAS:~/ruby/arduino$ bundle install | grep serial

Using serialport 1.3.1
greg@dom-NAS:~/ruby/arduino$

Comment: I see gem serial installed here:bundle show serialport
/home/greg/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/serialport-1.3.1

Comment: If you put it in your Gemfile then you shouldn't have to `require` it (thanks to Rails' autoloading). What happens if you remove that line? (In general when you do use `require` you don't want to do it inside a method. You should just do it at the top of the file, or in an initializer. However, it shouldn't be necessary at all here.)

Comment: You are right , require is not necessary . But the problem was with wrong ruby interpreter used by phusion passenger. I changed the config of passenger an it works.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by changing configuration of passenger which used wrong ruby interpreter. When I checked as a user in command line everything seemed to be ok, but using Apache/Passenger was an error, everything because different ruby interpreters used in these two situations.